# javascript - check if var is in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of integers `a=[1,3,5,7]` and `b=[2,4,6,8]`.
Now I need to check if a given var `$v` is in `a` and if it is, return the equivalent element from `b`. Example:

`if $v in a (and $x is its position) return $b[$x]`.

How do I perform this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `indexOf` method will return the index of the array where the item was found, or -1 if it wasn't found.

```
var i = a.indexOf(v);
if (i != -1)
{
    return b[i]
}
```

EDIT: This will add the method if your browser doesn't have it.

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
{
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(x)
    {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        {
            if (this[i] === x)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: The `Array.IndexOf` method is not available in IE 8 or earlier.

Comment: Rats. Edited the answer to add the method if it isn't there.

Answer (score 3):

Loop through the items in the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i] == v) {
    return b[i];
  }
}
return -1; // not found
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(a.indexOf(v) > -1) {
  var id = a.indexOf(v);
  console.log(b[id]);
}
```

See for compatibility of [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/IndexOf#Compatibility)

Comment: Note: The `Array.IndexOf` method is not available in IE 8 or earlier.

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = a.indexOf(v);
if (i !== -1)
{
    return b[i]
}
```

Comment: Note: The `Array.indexOf` method is not available in IE 8 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this would work.

```
>> function test(k){ return b[a.indexOf(k)]}

>> test(1)
2

>> test(9)
undefined
```

In js, `indexOf` always returns an integer and by calling an array with an integer (like `A[3]` ), it always returns a value or `undefined`. explicitly check for the `undefined` value if you want to make sure application code is not broken.

Comment: Note: The `Array.indexOf` method is not available in IE 8 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give below function a try. PHP.js is really a great collection of functions and salute to all contributors to make it what it is today.

http://phpjs.org/functions/in_array:432

Comment: Many a times PHP.js is a great place to learn many unexplored things with Javascript.